# Where should I place Recaptcha.dll in my asp.net mvc application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, captcha, recaptcha

So, I've implemented ReCaptcha in my ASP.NET MVC application via these instructions:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

My question is, after I've created my reference to my dll, where should I place the DLL in my solution?  Should I just make a references folder or ... ?

What is best practice on where I should place the recaptcha.dll in my project so the reference will work for others who pull down my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the `CaptchaValidatorAttribute` in the business logic layer and referenced the dllin that library.

As to physical location, in the project I placed the library in a ThirdPartLibrarys directory and referenced it there.

When the project comes down from source control, it will be in the right place for the reference. (Assuming your source control solution allows you to check in files from the file system.)